# How to force-stop an application in android programmatically

Tags: java, android

I am trying to force-stop other application programmatically if the user is not allowed to use the application. The force-stop is the same as by going to the Setting > Apps > Firefox > there will be a force stop button which can force stop an application.

```
private void forceStop(int currentPID, String currentProcessName){
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, currentProcessName);
        if(currentPID != -1){
            try {
                Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());

                os.writeBytes("adb shell" + "\n");

                os.flush();

                os.writeBytes("am force-stop " + currentProcessName + "\n");

                os.flush();
                Log.i("Executed","Kill " + currentPID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Handle error
            }
        } else {
            Log.i("Not Found","App Not Found");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
}
```

However, if i try to enter this command in the terminal of Android Studio, this will force stop the application:

```
    adb shell force-stop <packageName>
```

So how am i going to force-stop an application through the code programmatically?

P.S *My device is not root*

Comment: Why not just finish() your activity?  From a practical point of view its equivalent-  you're closing out the UI.

Comment: @GabeSechan The application that i am doing is such that the user can only access the whitelist application. However, if the user open an application for example: Firefox, the application will detect that it is not an whitelist application and will force stop Firefox as to prevent it from running in the background

Comment: You're not doing that without rooting. Do you see what a massive security issue that would be? And if you really need this, you ought to be a device policy power and just prevent any other app from being installed at all

Comment: I have a question in mind. Why is it when i enter adb shell force-stop <package name> in the android studio terminal it will work whereas if i put in the code, it doesn't work?